# How to resolve ZEIT NOW deployment error Error: Exited with 1

Tags: vercel

Deploying any project will now result the error shown below:

```
Error relocating /lib/libmount.so.1: secure_getenv: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libmount.so.1: getrandom: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libblkid.so.1: secure_getenv: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libblkid.so.1: getrandom: symbol not found
ERROR: gdk-pixbuf-2.40.0-r2.trigger: script exited with error 127

error building image: error building stage: waiting for process to exit: exit status 1
Error: Exited with 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/zeit/{{random_str}}/.build-utils/.builder/node_modules/@zeit-v1-read-only/now-builder-v1/dist/utils/await-child.js:23:31)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
```

`ERROR: gdk-pixbuf-2.40.0-r2.trigger: script exited with error 127` was an error shown previously but didn't seem to stop the script from completing the installation / build process. Does this have anything to do with npm packages that requires `node-gyp-build`?

Comment: hey, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Ebdulmomen66 Zeit 1.0 is dead already. We may not create new containers and the old ones will be removed in a few days.